# Joining same values in SQL and looping through them

Tags: php, sql

Consider this table in SQL:

```
REGION:        COUNTRY:
Lombardia      Italy
Sicily         Italy
Sardinia       Italy
Borgogne       France
Corsica        France
```

In PHP, How can I create a dropdown-menu for which, looping through the values, I have a unique Country name displayed and, under it, the different regions?

This is as far as I got, building a loop to display all the regions, but I need to divide them visually by country.

```
   $rowreg=mysql_num_rows($sqlreg);

      $sqlregione=mysql_query("select region from regions order by country");

      for($z = 0; $z < $rowreg; $z++){
         $rigareg = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlreg);           
         echo"<option>". $rigareg['regione']."</option>";
```

I thought about a nested array but it only brought me more confusion.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So you want a list containing "Italy", "Lombardia/Italy", "Sicily/Italy", etc.? And shall the user be able to pick the country without a region or is this supposed to be a non-clickable title?

Comment: Non-clickable title (the Country) and clickable Regions. Because it would be an input option field for a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the combobox look something like this:

```
France:
  Borgogne
  Corsica
Italy:
  Lombardia
  Sicily
  Sardinia
```

You can use the option's value attribute to store the country along with the region items.

I don't think, however, that you can really tweak a combobox in PHP so that some items are non-clickable and shown in another font or so to really look like a title. As I see it, there remain two options:

1. Make the countries clickable and alert the user if they mistakenly pick them.
2. Make the countries disabled items.

The code for filling the combobox:

```
$result = mysql_query("select country, region from regions union all select distinct country, null from regions order by country, region");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  if(is_null($row['region']))
    echo '<option value="' . $row['country'] . '" disabled>' . $row['country'] . '</option>';
  else
    echo '<option value="' . $row['region'] . '#' . $row['country'] . '">' . $row['region'] . '</option>';
}
```

Remove `disabled` if you want the countries clickable.

(I'm not fluent in PHP, so there may be slight errors in my code. Moreover, the PHP docs mention mysql_query as deprecated: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: It worked beautifully. Honestly I would never got to the idea of merging two selections and using the null field from the second one as the place to insert the region "title". Regarding the mysql library you are right but I am working for a client with a super old server configuration and they want to keep it. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the last country output to the list. If the current country is different, output the country as an option. On the first region the country will be different than the last country (which will be nothing).

But, those country options are going to be available to select in the dropdown list. So you may need to add validation that the user selected a region rather than a country.

Comment: I got to the point where now I have the associative arrays with ["italy"=>"sicily", "italy"=>"lombardia", "france"=>"borgogne", "france"=>"corsica"], etc. But now how can I loop through and not having the duplicate region keys?